# Cant get hover to change text color

Tags: css, colors, hover

I created a tab at the top of my page called `newarrival`, and when you hover over the tab I want the text to go blue so people know its a link ... but I just cant figured out why its not working. My tab is at the top of my page at : [www.greenieproducts.com](http://www.greenieproducts.com)

From what I know this css code should work :

```css
#newarrival a:hover 
{
  color:blue!important;
}
```

but its not working for me. I also tried

```css
a #newarrival : hover 
{
  color:blue!important;
}
```

Please somebody point me towards to right direction.
Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 2):

Your image:
http://greenieproducts.com/wp-content/themes/shopperpress/thumbs/greenie-12.png
is covering the a tag

Comment: @PhilippeAllaire To bring your `#newarrival` front give `z-index:1;`

Comment: @PhilippeAllaire remove !important

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
#newarrival a
{
  color:#00000 !important;
}

#newarrival a:hover 
{
  color:#F3F3F3 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [image](http://www.greenieproducts.com/wp-content/themes/shopperpress/thumbs/greenie-12.png) is coming in **front** of the `#newarrival` div. To bring the `#newarrival` div front of the image, just add `z-index:1` to its CSS properties and as Rohit Azad commented, remove `!important`.. Its not necessary here.

```
#newarrival
{
  /* Your other CSS properties */

  z-index:1;  /*Add this property */
}
```